# JTable in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, layout-manager

I am adding `JTable` in a `JScrollPane` then adding scrollpane to the panel, then adding panel to the frame but it doesn't work here's the code. I want to have scroll bar on table or frame that will make table scrollable so user can see it. I have tried many ways but non worked for me
  here is the whole code

```
public class View extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
//here in the main method i it adds in the JFrame everything

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                View frame = new View();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void showData() throws SQLException, ParseException {

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel_1 = new JPanel();
    model_1 = new DefaultTableModel();
    model_2 = new DefaultTableModel();

    model_1.addColumn("Title");
    model_1.addColumn("Priority ");
    model_1.addColumn("DeadLine");
    model_1.addColumn("Time");
    model_1.addColumn("Progress");

    model_2.addColumn("Task Title");
    model_2.addColumn("Priority ");
    model_2.addColumn("DeadLine");
    model_2.addColumn("Time");
    model_2.addColumn("Done");

    Database obj = new Database();

    ArrayList<Task> list = obj.getTasks();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        Task task = list.get(i);
        Object[] row = { task.title, task.priority, task.deadine,
                task.time, task.progress };

        // Comparing Dates

        Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-d-yyyy");
        String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());

        java.util.Date systemDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-d-yyyy",
                Locale.ENGLISH).parse(dateNow);

        if (!task.deadine.before(systemDate)) {
            // add row to to do tab
            model_1.addRow(row);
        } else {
            // add row to done tab
            model_2.addRow(row);
        }

        // **********************

    }

    toDoTable = new JTable(model_1);
    doneTable = new JTable(model_2);
    toDoTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    doneTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    toDoTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    doneTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

//here i add the JScrollPane  and it doesnt work 

    JScrollPane jpane = new JScrollPane(toDoTable);
    JScrollPane jpane1 = new JScrollPane(doneTable);

    panel.add(jpane);
    panel_1.add(jpane1);
    panel.add(jpane);
    panel_1.add(jpane1);

}
}
```

Comment: Post more code. Currently posted seems to be ok. How do you add the panels to main container? SSCCE?

Comment: Here instead of doing this, **panel.add(jpane);** try to add this panel to the a JScrollPane such that the table scrolls, **add(new JScrollPane(panel))**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your panel with proper layout for ex BorderLayout

```
  panel.add(jpane,BorderLayout.NORTH);
  panel_1.add(jpane1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

or you can use `javax.swing.Box`

```
 Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
 box.add(jpane);
 box.add(jpane1);
 frame.getContentPane().add(box);
```

Comment: I defined a border layout for the `JPanel` that held my `JScrollPane` but it only worked if I added the scroll pane component without defining a direction.  If I passed a direction in the `.add` function it broke.  Dunno why.

Answer (score 7):

If you want scroll inside a table then do,

```
   JScrollPane jpane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

But if you want the table itself to the scrolled then add the panel which is holding the table to the `JScrollPane` and add this to your frame.

```
public class JTableExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] column = {"One", "Two"};
    Object[][] data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};

    JTable toDoTable = new JTable(data, column);
    JScrollPane jpane = new JScrollPane(toDoTable);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    panel.add(jpane);
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(panel));
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: i did that but still its not working 
i am using windows builder for making GUI and its main method is like that
`
    public static void main(String[] args) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    try {
     View frame = new View();
     frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });
 }`

Comment: @PrinceVakas Firslty if you are new to Swing then please write code yourself instead of using UI-Builders. Update the _post_ with sample code which shows whole flow?

Comment: i did posted the whole class

Comment: like i said already theres problem in adding Jscroll bar to the Jtable i add JscrollPane and it doesnt show up. 
i have posted main method where it adds in jframe and the method where JTable adds in the panels

Comment: ideally that should work for me, unfortunately that's not working too. its OK i will leave it. anyways thank you for helping me

Comment: @PrinceVakas I have modified your code and now both tables are visible. I removed both Database and Task classes because I don't have that classes.

Comment: tables were always visible the problem is with the scroll bar it doesnt come while i add them in the frame with the tables

Comment: exactly i want the scroll bar when rows are more but that doesn't appear when i add it. it should appear in panel or with the table whenever rows exceed the size of frame